# Can't break out of a while statement

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function myFunction() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    let guess = prompt(' guess a number between 1 and 10');

    prompt(guess);

    while (guess != random) {

        alert(' you got it wrong!');

        if (guess === random) {
            break;
        }

    }

    alert(' you got it right! ');
}
myFunction();
```

I realize that this is a simple question but I'm a beginner and I can't seem to figure out why I'm unable to break out of an if statement. It'll continue to alert " You got it wrong!"

Comment: Your while loop needs to include prompting the user again

Comment: Both of the values are same i.e., random and guess. Once they are different, they will always remain different. You need to change one or both of the values inside your while loop so that they can meet your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is when you store value in guess using prompt it stores it as a string and not integer hence you might have to convert it to integer using parseInt() method.

Comment: True, but not the main issue here.